# Using GUI apps in WSL2

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I try to run emacs-gtk in Ubuntu 20.04 WSL. Previously, I had used this command to get the IP of the host, `/etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{print $2}'`, but now, I got this:

```
1.1.1.1
8.8.8.8
fe80::162e:5eff:fef0:12b6
```

My `/etc/wsl.conf` look like this:

```
# Enable DNS – even though these are turned on by default, we'll specify here just to be explicit.
[network]
generateHosts = true
generateResolvConf = true
```

And my /etc/hosts is this.

```
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [network]
# generateHosts = false
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       tizona.localdomain      tizona
﻿
192.168.1.76    host.docker.internal
192.168.1.76    gateway.docker.internal
127.0.0.1       kubernetes.docker.internal

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

What should I do to run GUI applications? Is it an Ubuntu issue or related to Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping that you're enjoying your day. There is a simple application to do this called "GWSL". It's on the MS store, and you can get it from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/p/gwsl/9nl6kd1h33v3?activetab=pivot:overviewtab). I hope this helps!